# Datatype changed after IMPORT of schema

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, oracle11gr2, impdp, expdp

please advice on EXPDP and IMPDP utilities, Oracle 12c DB administration.

We exported schema `TEST` (DB 11.2.0.4) using `EXPDB` utility 
and imported dump file to new DB (DB 12.2.0.1.0) using `IMPDP` utility.

After import we checked one of tables - stock.
it has column `SAP_MM` - Datatype changed to `FLOAT(126)`.
but in source DB it has `NUMBER(38)`.

May be someone came across such issue - datatype conversion. 
What can be the reason?

Comment: Did you run the import with `TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=REPLACE`?

Comment: No, i did not. Can it be the source of problem?

Comment: If the table already existed with the wrong definition, then the import would not change it

Comment: thanks for reply, I will check.